# How do I use recursion with kotlin coroutines with yield

Tags: kotlin

im trying to experiment in kotlin using kotlins yield functionality.

This function should return the union of two sequences, and looks like this:

```
fun <T>Sequence<T>.union(seq : Sequence<T>): Sequence<T> = sequence {
if (any()) {
    if (seq.contains(first())) {
        yield(first())
    }
    drop(0).union(seq)
}
}
```

When I run this function with these two sequences:

```
val seq2 = (1..30).asSequence()
val seq3 = (1..32).asSequence()
```

It just returns a sequence of [1], it doesnt do any recursive calls at all. What am I doing wrong, why is the recursive union() call not activated at all?

Comment: You don't do anything with `drop(0).union(seq)`.

Comment: how would i then make recursive calls?

Comment: `yieldAll(drop(0).union(seq))`, for example